# Keep nav menu open if child item is active in a vertical list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on Vertical list and list shows child item when user clicks on the parent item and also changes the color of the child item in red if it matches the URL.

I want the parent nav in open state if it's child item has an `active-menu` class.

I am using below script but it's not working, not sure what I am missing

[Fiddle code](https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/ExaWxmm)

```js
$(".nav-w > ul > li > a").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


//open active list
$('.nav-w ul li').children().has('.active-menu').css('display', 'block');


// compare url with nav url to show active url 
$(function() {
  //var url = window.location.href;
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(
    window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
  );
  $(".nav-w ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == url || $(this).attr("href") == "") {
      $(this).addClass("active-menu");
    }
  });

  console.log("url : " + window.location.pathname);
});
```

```css
.nav-w a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* color: #178B43 !important; */
  color: #757575;
}


/* ul inside content area*/

.nav-w ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-w ul li {
  /*padding-left: 10px;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* ol inside content area*/

.nav-w>ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav-w ul>li ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.active-menu {
  color: red !important;
}

.nav-w>ul li::after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-w>ul li ul li::after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-w ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.nav-w a:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-left: 2px solid #178B43;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-w">

  <ul class="">
    <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Share Information</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-overview/">Share Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-graph/">Share Graph </a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/investor-calculator/">Investement Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-prices/">Historical Share Prices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Financial Information</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/earning-releases/">Earning Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/financial-statements/">Financial Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/presentation">Presentation
</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/quarterly-key-figures">Quarterly Key Figures
</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/annual-key-figures">Annual Key Figures
</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected your script,

```
$('.nav-w ul li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active-menu')) {
    $(this).parents("ul").css('display', 'block');
  }
})
```

`$('.nav-w ul li')` will return array of elements, you will need run loop through it to find active element then open it's parent.

I have manually added `active-menu` class to below `li` to test the code.

```
<li class="active-menu"><a href="{...}">Earning Releases</a></li>
```

```js
$(".nav-w > ul > li > a").click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});


//open active list
$('.nav-w ul li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active-menu')) {
    $(this).parents("ul").css('display', 'block');
  }
})


// compare url with nav url to show active url 
$(function() {
  //var url = window.location.href;
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(
    window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1
  );
  $(".nav-w ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == url || $(this).attr("href") == "") {
      $(this).addClass("active-menu");
    }
  });

  console.log("url : " + window.location.pathname);
});
```

```css
.nav-w a {
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* color: #178B43 !important; */
  color: #757575;
}


/* ul inside content area*/

.nav-w ul {
  margin-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.nav-w ul li {
  /*padding-left: 10px;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}


/* ol inside content area*/

.nav-w>ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav-w ul>li ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: none;
}

.active-menu {
  color: red !important;
}

.nav-w>ul li::after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-w>ul li ul li::after {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 32px;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.nav-w ul li ul li a {
  padding-left: 45px;
}

.nav-w a:hover {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-left: 2px solid #178B43;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-w">

  <ul class="">
    <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Share Information</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-overview/">Share Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-graph/">Share Graph </a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/investor-calculator/">Investement Calculator</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/share-nformations/share-prices/">Historical Share Prices</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" style="cursor: default;">Financial Information</a>
      <ul class="" style="display: none;">
        <li class="active-menu"><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/earning-releases/">Earning Releases</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/financial-statements/">Financial Statements</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/presentation">Presentation
</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/quarterly-key-figures">Quarterly Key Figures
</a></li>
        <li><a href="/investor-relations/financial-information/annual-key-figures">Annual Key Figures
</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```